# customization of window in standout library android

Tags: android

I came to know about [Standout](https://github.com/pingpongboss/StandOut) library by [Mark Wei](https://github.com/pingpongboss) for Android to create floating apps. But I can't customize the window in it. If anyone have used it please help me with the links to learn customizing these floating windows.

They have Inbuilt frame which comes with close, minimize etc. actions

I can't use in my application. as Frame minimizes space for Image.
I just want to add Image and Close button in it.

Though the code in library is self Explanatory,
I have added the close button in that window but can't link this button to method which close the floating window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `FLAG_DECORATION_SYSTEM` and I can remove the default frame.

```
  @Override
        public int getFlags(int id) {
            return StandOutFlags.FLAG_DECORATION_SYSTEM
                    | StandOutFlags.FLAG_BODY_MOVE_ENABLE
                    | StandOutFlags.FLAG_WINDOW_HIDE_ENABLE
                    | StandOutFlags.FLAG_WINDOW_BRING_TO_FRONT_ON_TAP
                    | StandOutFlags.FLAG_WINDOW_EDGE_LIMITS_ENABLE
                    | StandOutFlags.FLAG_WINDOW_PINCH_RESIZE_ENABLE;
        }
```

And I have added custom Close button to that layout and in its onClick action I have added Following code,

```
Button close = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_close);
        close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                close(ID);
            }
        });
```

This Solved My problem to customize window with only Image and Close button,
Thanks TO [Mark wei](https://github.com/pingpongboss) Creator of this Library.